# OpenGL ES 2.0 Android Clipping Color

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

i'm using my fragment shader to clip objects in OpenGL ES 2.0. Everything is working well, however the colour of the clipped surface is all black... I can not figure out how to change the colour (well ideally I'd want to make a similar texture to the rest of the object. I have included the code for my fragment shader below.

```
       precision mediump float; 

       varying vec2 texCoord;
       varying vec3 v_Normal;
       varying vec3 v_Position;
       varying vec4 originalPosition;

       uniform sampler2D texSampler2D;
       uniform vec3 lightPosition;
       uniform vec4 lightColor;

       void main()
       {
          vec3 L = normalize(lightPosition - v_Position);
          vec3 N = normalize(v_Normal);
          float NdotL = max(dot(N,L),0.0);

         if(originalPosition.y >= 2.0){
              discard;
         }else{
              gl_FragColor = NdotL * lightColor * texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord);
         }
       }
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the problem. Are you saying that it renders properly without the `if`/discard` in the shader code? And if you add that, everything turns black?

Comment: Okay so here is a picture of what I have. http://imgur.com/KZwpgIP

Comment: I don't want the black centre top thing... rather I wanted it to be something similar to rest of the texture.

Answer (score 0):

Using [discard](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/discard.php) in a fragment shader doesn't render anything to the pixel, it just leaves it exactly as it was before, so the black color is probably your clear color or whatever you had rendered previously. If you want to render a particular color to the pixels you are currently discarding, add another `uniform` to your shader for the clip color, like this:

```
 uniform vec4 clipColor;
```

Set it in the same way you set the `lightColor`, then instead of discarding the pixel when clipping, you can set the pixel to the clip color:

```
if(originalPosition.y >= 2.0) {
     gl_FragColor = clipColor;
} else {
     gl_FragColor = NdotL * lightColor * texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord);
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I get something like [this...](http://imgur.com/GYxSaan)
Where the clipColor is white, however I want it so that the object looks sliced/clipped as it does when I use discard, as shown [here](http://imgur.com/KZwpgIP)

Comment: I want to remove the black surface on the top in the second image.

Comment: Can you just set the desired clip color as your clear color and render as you were originally?

Comment: Just to confirm, it's not actually possible to set a color for discarded pixels, because when you use the discard keyword, no pixels are actually written.

Comment: I wasn't able to set a color to them, I'm not sure if it's even possible. I'd love to know if someone figures it out.